# Export Paper Model addon installation problems in 2.8 Beta

Tags: export, add-on

I have tried to manually install the Export Paper Model addon to my copy of Blender 2.8 Beta, and it won't appear in the Add Ons section of my Preferences menu. Has anybody had a similar problem?

[Here is a link to the addon.](https://github.com/addam/Export-Paper-Model-from-Blender)

Comment: Can you share a link to it? Don't know this addon, there are billions...

Comment: @brockmann Done! Thank you for your comment, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: The addon is versioned for `"blender": (2, 73, 0),`  Because of the major changes between 2.8 and 2.7x  addons with versions prior to 2.80 are disabled and will not show up in addons list. There will be a message in system console on start up.

Comment: It appears when selecting the python file. However it needs to be updated for 2.8, there are a few changes: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API